# Create a photo album on Facebook through the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fiddler

I am trying to create a FB photo album, so that I can use that album in a FB AD. I am using the following request on fiddler:

POST https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{page_id}/albums

and I pass the page access token in the body of the request. I keep getting this reply:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires extended permission: manage_pages and publish_pages","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"FCspsWIecMV"}}
```

After a lot of research, I found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZ28bjBNk6I

This video shows how to give extended permissions, which seems to be the problem, but it is not working properly. I used the following query to give the necessary permission to myself:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={ap_id}&redirect_uri={our_page}&scope=publish_pages
```

But it only redirects me to the 'our_page' link. But the first time I have used this link, with "manage_pages" in the scope, it actually has shown me the page in which I had to allow this permission. So I guess the query is correct, because by querying the /me/permissions I get this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "manage_pages",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "public_profile",
      "status": "granted"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any tip on how I can get this done?

Comment: Easiest way, if you only need this once: Use [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), choose your app from the dropdown, click on Get Token -> Get User Access Token ...

Comment: thanks :) I found out a better and long lasting way that I will post as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that, by selecting the app in the [https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer](http://Graph%20API), the necessary permissions are then shown for the specific request. After clicking there, all my requests started to work, so it seems that this method is permanent. Below there's an illustrative screenshot of how to do it.

[image: The permission needed, publish pages, is shown in the dropdown toolbar]